# How to fix an SQL query which has a specifying table twice error

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this query:

```
SELECT *
FROM `wp_postmeta`
WHERE `meta_key` = '_test'
  AND `post_id` IN (SELECT post_id FROM `wp_postmeta`
                    where meta_value = 8023)
```

Returns the SQL error:

> Table 'wp_postmeta' is specified twice, both as a target for 'UPDATE'
>   and as a separate source for data

I have read other answers and attempting to add a further `SELECT * FROM ( )` around the sub query but didn't help.

I assume I need some form of `AS` in here but can't figure out the exact code.

Can you rewrite the query in the format that won't trigger the error?

The same for this similar query:

```
UPDATE wp_postmeta
SET meta_value = 5.55
WHERE meta_key = '_regular_price'
AND post_id IN (
    SELECT post_id
    FROM wp_postmeta
    WHERE meta_value = 8023
)`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use alias for table name
 (and  as suggestion in your case you can also use join  instead of in )

```
  SELECT a.*
  FROM `wp_postmeta` a
  inner join  `wp_postmeta` b on  a.`post_id = b.post_id 
  where a.`meta_key` = '_test'
  and b.meta_value = 8023
```

In update you could  use a join with subselect for  circumvent the limits due to update actions on the same table

```
  UPDATE wp_postmeta a
  inner join (
    SELECT post_id
    FROM wp_postmeta
    WHERE meta_value = 8023
  ) t on  a.`post_id = t.post_id and a.`meta_key` = '_test'
  SET meta_value = 5.55
```

Comment: Hi that works great, but how do I use this if the query is an UPDATE and SET? (I've updated the question with my code)

Comment: answer  update  ..  but remember that change a question after  a first
 (correct ) answer is not fair  ..  ....

Comment: Syntax error: near 'b on  a.`post_id = t.post_id 
   SET meta_value = 5.55
  where a.`meta_key` = ' at line 6

Comment: Ending quote ` was expected. (near "" at position 213)
An alias was previously found. (near "` = '_test' SET meta_value = 5.55" at position 177)
Unexpected token. (near "` = '_test' SET meta_value = 5.55" at position 177)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM wp_postmeta  as wp_out 
WHERE wp_out.meta_key = '_test' 
          AND wp_out.post_id IN 
              ( SELECT wp_in.post_id 
                FROM wp_postmeta  as wp_in 
                where wp_in.meta_value = 8023)
```

Comment: Works but how would would I write this to work with the update/set (see 'similar query' in question)

Answer (score 0):

Although this is not a good answer, but it is effective, ha ha..
SELECT *
FROM `wp_postmeta`
WHERE `meta_key` = '_test'
  AND `post_id` IN (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(post_id) FROM `wp_postmeta`
                    where meta_value = 8023)

Answer (score 0):

The `SELECT` query posted in the question is equivalent to this one:

```
SELECT p1.*
FROM `wp_postmeta` p1
  INNER JOIN `wp_postmeta` p2 ON p1.`post_id` = p2.`post_id`
WHERE p1.`meta_key` = '_test'
  AND p2.`meta_value` = 8023
```

In fact, if some conditions are met, the MySQL engine converts the original `SELECT` query into a query similar to this as an [optimization](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/semi-joins.html).

This `SELECT` query can be easily changed into the desired `UPDATE` query:

```
UPDATE `wp_postmeta` p1
  INNER JOIN `wp_postmeta` p2 ON p1.`post_id` = p2.`post_id`
SET p1.`meta_values` = 5.55
WHERE p1.`meta_key` = '_test'
  AND p2.`meta_value` = 8023
```